# Duplicate key issue when loading back.json file PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, loaddata, dumpdata

I have a PostgreSQL database that where I performed python manage.py dumpdata to backup the data into a json file. I created a new PostgreSQL database, performed a migrate, and everything worked like clockwork. When I tried to load the backup.json file with python manage.py loaddata backup.json it, gives me this error.

```
Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=15): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_app_label_76bd3d3b_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (app_label, model)=(navigation, navigation) already exists.
```

I checked phpPgAdmin, and there is a row for News. Is there a way to load the backup json file without including the content types, or better yet dump everything except for content types data ?

Comment: if you just exclude ContentTypes - you might hit another duplicate and another, and another. It needs wider approach change I think

Comment: There are some differences between a postgres native `pg_restore` and django `loaddata`. This article clearly explains these differences and possible solutions - http://deephacks.com/articles/entry/django-backups-dumpdata-versus-sql-dump-postgresql-and-mysql/ But as @Vao Tsun advices, it would be better to find these constraint issues deep into your data.

Answer (score 29):

I was getting similar error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture
>   '/home/knysys/ogmius/ogmius/db.json': Could not load
>   contenttypes.ContentType(pk=2): duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq" DETAIL:
>   Key (app_label, model)=(auth, user) already exists

After that, I found out that If you are **restoring a fresh database** from another database, You need to **dumpdata** like this:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

and then load fresh database like this:

```
./manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Comment: this works but now I can not log in

Comment: @sutan it seems that the loaddata command has overwrite your users table also. Maybe you have a user from where you have loaded your db.json.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following command to load data:

```
python manage.py loaddata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes back.json
```

Comment: Cheers. Just to add, to prevent your user from being overwritten also add `--exclude auth.user`. And i also needed to add `--exclude admin.logentry` as i was getting an error relating to content_type ids from uninstalled apps