exporting data from sqlite database to postgress database in django
i wanted to transform my data from sqlite database onto posgres database in django. first of all i write the command:
python -Xutf8 .\manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 --output=data.json

to exporting data (in utf-8 encode) in a json file. everything was good and data exported properly, but when i want to import data in postgres (after configuration in settings.py) so i used
python .\manage.py loaddata data.json 

and got this error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\Bardia\Desktop\webapp\data.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=7): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (app_label, model)=(blog, post) already exists.

can anyone help my in this situation?
thanks a lot
loading data in new postgres database in django

Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416877/duplicate-key-issue-when-loading-back-json-file-postgresql
it looks like there is already a model in your new database

Go to Python shell and clear all ContentType data
python manage.py shell

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()


Thanks to a friend's answer and a bit of searching, my problem was solved with the following commands:
python manage.py shell

>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ContentType.objects.all().delete()

or do this:
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes

